# How to understand "Index signature is missing in type ... (2344)" Error?

Tags: typescript

For the following types,

```
interface MyObject {
  [key: string]: string| number;
}

type ValuesOf<T extends MyObject> = T[keyof T];

type S = ValuesOf<['1','2','3']>; // Type '["1", "2", "3"]' does not satisfy the constraint 'MyObject'. Index signature is missing in type '["1", "2", "3"]'.(2344)
```

But if I change `MyObject` to

```
interface MyObject {
  [key: string]: any; // <-- replace string| number with any;
}
```

then the error is gone. How to understand this?

Edit: I just want to understand why TS behaves this way, not aiming to make the above code work.

Comment: Hmm, someone smarter than me can tell you why `any` works, but an array is an object with a `number` key, so `[key: number]: string | number;` would work

Comment: As an aside, `type ValuesOf<T> = T[keyof T]` works just fine without a constraint on `T`.

Comment: The complete signature of `Array` contains both `number` keys (the values in the array) and `string` keys (the methods of [`class Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Instance_properties)). However, not all values associated to `string` keys are of type `number|string` (actually, apart from `length`, the other are functions). Therefore, the signature of type `Array` does not match the original signature of `interface MyObject` but it matches both `[key: number]: string | number` and `[key: string]: any`.

Comment: @axiac, the problem is that `[key: string]: string| number | Function` does not work either.

Comment: It does not work because of [`@@unscopables`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@unscopables) that is a [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol). I would try a different approach; enumerating all possible types of the values of some object is not going to work much.

Comment: ok, adding `Symbol` still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

`['1','2','3']` is an [`Array`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array), its keys that are associated to values of type `string` are of type `number`. It does not match the definition of `interface MyObject` that describes an object with keys of type `string`. The values associated to the keys of type `string` of `Array` are its methods and their types are `function`. This is why `Array` matches the definition `{ [key: string]: any }`.

It works fine if you change the definition of `interface MyObject` to expect numeric keys (but it may not be what you need, though):

```js
interface MyObject {
  [key: number]: string| number;
}

type ValuesOf<T extends MyObject> = T[keyof T];

type S = ValuesOf<['1','2','3']>;
```

Check it on the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMZAbwFgAoZZAbQGsJ0AuZEAVwFttoBdZgZzBRQAcwA+LDlygBuCgF8KFMOgAOKAGpwANqwh9MMADwAVZBAAekEABM+aLHgJgAfMgC8yY3QYB7GJ+5ZciVVFABld2RNHT0DQ2oAcgBGBIAaBIAmNISAZgTuZ2kgA).

Comment: I am not sure I understand your answer since I only change the value type, not key type, and your are saying the error is due to key type?

Answer (score 0):

Correct interface for `MyObject` in your case is:

```js
interface MyObject {
    [key: number]: string | number;
}
```

Because You are using here an array with string elements. Array has only numeric keys. So, You should use only `[key: number]` for array indexing.

I'd rather use next approach for getting array elements:

```js
type ValuesOfArray<T extends Array<unknown>> = T[number]
type S = ValuesOfArray<['1', '2', '3']>; // "1" | "2" | "3"
```

Here is generic type for values:

```js
type GenericValues<T> = T extends Array<any> ? T[number]: T[keyof T];
```

`Type '["1", "2", "3"]' does not satisfy the constraint 'MyObject'. Index signature is missing in type '["1", "2", "3"]'` means that numeric index signature of array is not compatible with your string signature